# What does the cron response /bin/bash: 1: command not found mean

Tags: bash

I have the following 3 crons inplace:

```
php /home/mycpanelaccess/public_html/wpradmin/modules/wprrets/cron_data.php >> /home/mycpanelaccess/public_html/reports/data.htm 2>&1   

php /home/mycpanelaccess/public_html/pins/update-time.php >> /home/mycpanelaccess/public_html/reports/data.htm >2&1

php /home/mycpanelaccess/public_html/wpradmin/mbx/Modules/GeoCoding/GeoCron.php >> /home/mycpanelaccess/public_html/reports/data.htm 2>&1
```

They all work perfect and carry out their orders one by one each hour in the ordrer listed.. however the center one the update-time.php does the job but sends the following response "/bin/bash: 1: command not found"

Even  though it activates and does the job but sends the response to the email and does not enter any data at the report point like the others do.

Any thoughts.. does anyone need to see the program to eval... seems like the 2>&1 may be a problem as it seems to be pointing out the 1 as part of the bash.... but if the command cannot be found how did it fill in the dates in the data base as requested.. it carried out all commands but failed to send its output the the /reports/data.htm file... but other wise its fine...

Comment: Replace `>2&1` by `2>&1`.

Comment: Thanks will try that.. will leave the other two urls alone and change just the failing one.. does that sound good or i need to change them all 3... other two are reproting back fine..

Comment: OMG.. good example of HUPA.. just pulled it out.. of course i only need to change the one.. the rest were right and i just over looked it.. thanks a lot.. sometimes we are so blind we cannot see..

Comment: Also, look for a leftover output file named "2".

Answer (score 2):

Just to explain what happens, here is a simplified version of the incorrect line :

```
php my/php/script.php >> logfile >2&1
```

Here is what it looks like, rearranged to be equivalent but more how usually written :

```
php my/php/script.php >>logfile >2 & 1
```

What happens :

- The command seen by the shell is `php my/php/script.php` (no surprise there)
- `>>logfile` redirects standard output to append to the log file
- `>2` redirects standard output to overwrite file `2` (the first redirection is replaced, and nothing will be appended to the log file)
- `&` causes the whole preceding command to be launched in the background
- `1` is seen as a separate command, and since there is no command named `1`, you get the error message you saw

As already commented, the solution is to rewrite it like the other lines :

```
php my/php/script.php >> logfile 2>&1
```